# How to set background image for each partial from the main page (index.html) and ng-app module

Tags: angularjs

I have index.html (main page) with basic layout. For content I'm using ng-view with partials.

Now since apart from the background image for body (which is html body excluding header, nav-bar and footer) which is different for the home partial view from all the other remaining views, all the contents in partial views render on a specific location defined by ng-view.

I want to know the angular way to deal with this sort of situation.

As of now, I've taken the whole body  into partial and rendered the background image from there.

But I was thinking of setting the background from index.html taking into account the location Url (which is different for each partial view) and render all the partials from a specific box in the index.html.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Angular Way is, as you say, to "render all the partials from a specific box in the index.html".

See the AngularJS tutorial on Routing & Multiple Views:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

---

**Update in response to comment:**

Create a new controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', [$scope, function ($scope) {
    $scope.bgimg = "image.jpg";
}]);
```

For your "top-level" `<div>` in index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" style="background-image: url({{ bgimg }})">
...
</div>
```

---

**Update #2 in response to comment:**

In the controllers for the partials, and also for the "MyCtrl" controller above, inject `$rootScope`, and use `$rootScope` to set the background image for the main page:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('Ctrl01', [$rootScope, function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.bgimg = "image.jpg";
}]);
```

Comment: The only problem is that the background image (which is not in the box but whole "body") is different for one partial (home) from others (register, etc.). So even if I render all the partials on a specific box, the background image spans the whole body and can't be changed from partial( which is restricted only for that box).

Comment: I can do all that, but the only way to decide which background image to use for a particular partial, do I have to just look up the URl to know what is the current partial? How do I know which partial is rendered at any time? Note that my Url is different for each partial.

Comment: Then my suggestion would be to use $rootScope - I have updated my answer.